# Angular in memory web api cyclic dependency with httpClient

Tags: angular

I try to use the `angular-in-memory-web-api` (version 0.5.1). This works fine if I set up the "database" with local objects, but it fails if I try to get my data from local JSON files over an http request with following error:

> Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
>   Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! HttpClient ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1

as soon as I import the `httpClient` package into my service.

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService } from 'app/shared/services/in-memory-data.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// other imports of app components

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),    // always import after the HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [ // app wide services not concerning the problem ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in-memory-data.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { RequestInfo } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

@Injectable()
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {       
  // constructor(http: HttpClient) { // this creates the cyclic dependency
  constructor() {

  }    
  createDb(reqInfo?: RequestInfo) {
    const db = {}   
    // fetch data from local JSON files and set up "database" object    
    return db;
  }

}
```

Is this problem related to the `HttpClientModule` or is it an `angular-in-memory-web-api` problem?

Comment: Well, don't use InMemoryWebApiModule if you are looking to make requests to json file. For that, just make http get requests with the httpclient.

Comment: Initializing the in-memory database service from a JSON files is what I want to do and therefore I have to request JSON files because it's quite some data...

Comment: yes, request the json files, NOT inmemorywebapi.

Comment: Have you found the answer for the same?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem and that is how I was able to solve it, do not inject in the constructor but try to do that in the method.

From your createDB you will have httpclient injected correctly without the cyclic error.

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { RequestInfo } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

@Injectable()
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {  
  httpClient: HttpClient;
  constructor(private inject: Injector) {

  }    
  createDb(reqInfo?: RequestInfo) {
    const db = {}   
    this.httpClient = this.inject.get(HttpClient);
    // fetch data from local JSON files and set up "database" object    
    return db;
  }

}
```